# success and failed image in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i try to upload documents in asp.net 
 i add two images one is success and other is failed when image successfully uploaded then i show image and same as failed how i done this 
here is code

```
<div><img id="imgsuces" runat="server" src="images/successs.png" visible="false" alt="success" />
     <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" />
    </div>
    <div><img id="imgfalied" src="images/failed.png" runat="server" visible="false" alt="success" />
     <asp:Label runat="server" id="Label2" />
    </div>
    <div id="Something" visible="false">
```

and i call label

```
    StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    //StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold;
    StatusLabel.Text = "Success";
}
catch
{
    StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    Label2.Text = "Failed";
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to set

```
    imgsuces.Visible = true;
```